# Save Tree array in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.3

```
Array
(
    [Root] => Array
        (
            [Parent0] => Array
                (
                    [Child0] => Child0
                )

            [Parent1] => Array
                (
                    [Child1] => Child1
                )

        )

)
```

Above tree array need to be save in mysql with parent id so results should be like below:

```
id  parent_id   name
1   0           Root
2   1           Parent0
3   2           Child0
4   1           Parent1
5   4           Child1
```

Any one please let me know how can i save above results in mysql using php.

Thanks in advance for quick response.

Comment: you can traverse the array from the root recursively and save what u want, any way the parent id you've give seems wrong for the given example

Comment: thanks for your comments but Nothing wrong results are expected.

Comment: you can use array_walk_recursive  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the perfect working script in any depth level tree.

```
$root_id;
$parent_id = 0;

foreach ( $tree_array as $root_key => $root_value ) {

    $parent_id = insertRecord($root_key, $parent_id);
    $root_id = $parent_id;

    if ( is_array($root_value) ) {
        foreach ( $root_value as $parent_key => $parent_value ) {

            $parent_id = insertRecord($parent_key, $root_id);
            $keep_parent_id = $parent_id;

            if ( is_array($parent_value) ) {
                foreach ( $parent_value as $child_key => $child_value ) {

                    $parent_id = insertRecord($child_key, $keep_parent_id);
                    getlevel($child_value, $parent_id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function getlevel($sub_childs, $new_parent_id) {
    $keep_new_parent_id = $new_parent_id;

    if ( is_array($sub_childs) ) {
        foreach ( $sub_childs as $sub_child => $sub_child_sub ) {

            $new_parent_id = insertRecord($sub_child, $keep_new_parent_id);
            if ( is_array($sub_child_sub) ) {
                getlevel($sub_child_sub, $new_parent_id);
            }
        }
    }
}

function insertRecord($name, $parent_id) {
    $q = "insert into xtable set name = '".$name."',  parent_id = '".$parent_id."'";
    mysql_query($q);

    $folder_id = mysql_insert_id();

    return $folder_id;
}
```

Thanks to everyone for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:**EDITED**

```
         $c=0;
    $x;
    foreach($array1 as $key=>$val){
        if(is_array($val)){
            echo "insert $key with parent id $c<br>";
            $c++;
            $x=$c; 
            foreach($val as $key1=>$val1){          
                echo " insert $key1 with parent id $x<br>";
   $c++;

                if(is_array($val1)){
                    foreach($val1 as $key2=>$val2){
                      echo "insert $key2 with parent id $c<br>";
                         $c++;
                        getlevel($val2,$c);
                    }
                }/* else{
                    echo "else insert $key1 with parent id $c<br>";
                    $c++; */
                }

            }

        }


    function getlevel($value,$c1){
        if(is_array($value)){
            foreach($value as $keyV=>$Value){
                echo " insert $keyV with parent id $c1<br>";
                $c1++;
                if(is_array($Value)){
                    getlevel($Value,$c1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

where ever i have written echo replace with your sql.Hope it helps.here `$array` is your array.

Comment: It's not correct script it is failed in depth level.

Comment: In which case failed check this FYI:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479234/how-to-insert-the-tree-in-database-using-php-mysql?noredirect=1#comment39765598_25479234

Answer (score -1):

If you want to achieve parent child tree you can go for the below code with n depth

```
 Automobile
        Fuel
            Gasoline
            Diesel
        Maintenance
    Food
        Fish
        Pork
```

First create a database table named “categories” that has fields.

```
- category_id (PK int)
- parent_id (int)
- title (varchar)

<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ( mysql_error() );
    mysql_select_db("test");
    $nav_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` ORDER BY `category_id`") or die( mysql_error() );
    $tree = ""; // Clear the directory tree
    $depth = 1; // Child level depth.
    $top_level_on = 1; // What top-level category are we on?
    $exclude = array(); // Define the exclusion array
    array_push($exclude, 0); // Put a starting value in it

   while ( $nav_row = mysql_fetch_array($nav_query) )
   {
      $goOn = 1; // Resets variable to allow us to continue building out the tree.
      for($x = 0; $x < count($exclude); $x++ ) // Check to see if the new item has been used
      {
          if ( $exclude[$x] == $nav_row['category_id'] )
          {
             $goOn = 0;
             break; // Stop looking b/c we already found that it's in the exclusion list and we can't continue to process this node
          }
      }
      if ( $goOn == 1 )
      {
          $tree .= $nav_row['title'] . "<br>"; // Process the main tree node
          array_push($exclude, $nav_row['category_id']); // Add to the exclusion list
          if ( $nav_row['category_id'] < 6 )
          { $top_level_on = $nav_row['category_id']; }

          $tree .= build_child($nav_row['category_id']); // Start the recursive function of building the child tree
       }
    }

   function build_child($oldID) // Recursive function to get all of the children...unlimited depth
   {
       global $exclude, $depth; // Refer to the global array defined at the top of this script
       $tempTree = "";
       $child_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE parent_id=" . $oldID);
       while ( $child = mysql_fetch_array($child_query) )
       {
          if ( $child['category_id'] != $child['parent_id'] )
          {
             for ( $c=0;$c<$depth;$c++ ) // Indent over so that there is distinction between levels
             { $tempTree .= " "; }
             $tempTree .= "- " . $child['title'] . "<br>";
             $depth++; // Incriment depth b/c we're building this child's child tree (complicated yet???)
             $tempTree .= build_child($child['category_id']); // Add to the temporary local tree
             $depth--; // Decrement depth b/c we're done building the child's child tree.
             array_push($exclude, $child['category_id']); // Add the item to the exclusion list
          }
       }
       return $tempTree; // Return the entire child tree
     }

     echo $tree;

?>
```

You can copy paste the above code and you are done :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply but i'm looking for script which will save my above tree array into mysql. your script is for making tree.

Comment: @VinodPatidar The above code is to generate the tree from DB are you looking to insert the tree?

Then at each insert you need to check the parent in the database if its there select its id and insert as a parentid in the row if the parent is not there then insert it in the table with parent id 0 which will make it parent and then insert the child row with its id

Comment: Hi Dear, i did but no success can you please write script for me.i would like to  insert the tree in DB.